# how to fix issue with raspberry pi that can't get out to the internet after recent changes related to wireguard/vpn

Tags: linux, networking, routing, raspberry-pi, routing-table

I have a raspberry pi (bullseye) that can no longer connect to the internet after recent changes related to trying to get wireguard/vpn working.

Here is the routing table:

```
   route -n
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
   0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
   0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
   10.172.124.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
   169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     208    0        0 veth47c79f7
   172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
   172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-405564307d93
   192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
   192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

From my understanding, if I ping 8.8.8.8 it should go through eth0. However, it looks like its going through wg0

```
   pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ ip route get 8.8.8.8
   8.8.8.8 dev wg0 table 51820 src 10.172.124.1 uid 1000
       cache
```

When I ping using eth0, it connects:

```
   pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8
   PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.1.148 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=11.8 ms
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=9.08 ms
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=13.2 ms
```

but not with the default interface:

```
   pi@raspberrypi4:~ $ ping 8.8.8.8
   PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
   ^C
   --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
   6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5119ms
```

Any suggestions where the issue may be? Thanks!

Comment: `Any suggestions where the issue may be?` most likely a bad wireguard setup

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I believe so but I'm not sure where it went wrong.

Comment: it's even harder for us to know!